# showModalDialog - Is it possible to Dynamically Resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I'm using a showModalDialog for opening a Dialog inside a Dialog, although sometimes the dialog will have more fields depending on the information required. Is it possible to make this resize dynamically rather than giving it a fixed size?

```
    showModalDialog(
    v_location,
    '',
    'dialogHeight:260px; dialogWidth:560px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: No; status: Yes; scroll: Yes'
);
```

Comment: @johnMcElreavey: John, I hope that you do know that showModalDialog has been announced as deprecated function in some browsers. Think it is time to switch to Ajax modal windows as a replacement and solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
   showModalDialog(
v_location,
'',
'dialogHeight:260px; dialogWidth:560px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: Yes; status: Yes; scroll: Yes');
```

That will give you window which can be resized by user/visitor.
And yes it is possible to dynamically change size of the windows based for example on screen resolution, you will need to replace 'dialogHeight:260px; dialogWidth:560px;...' with something like 
'dialogHeight:<%=WindowsHeight%>px; dialogWidth:<%=WindowWidth%>px;...'
Specifics will depend on what your needs are.